# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'title' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, tornado

У меня есть условие

```
if title in info:
```

Так подробнее:

```
def post(self):
    info = self.request.body

    try:
        info = json.loads(info) if info is not False else False

        if info is not False:

            if title in info:
                title = info["title"]
```

Почему на него возникает эта ошибка, ведь это обычное условие?

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'title' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

info - JSON объект. Вам нужно проверить содержит ли объект info ключ 'title'.

```
if 'title' in info:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 2):

title в вашем коде написано как переменная, но нигде она не создаётся. А так как info - словарь, то в нём не может быть готовой переменной

title - объект-строка, а значит и пишется в кавычках.

```
if "title" in info:
    title = info["title"]
```